# decode morse code by character swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift-playground, morse-code

I am trying to make a morse code converter in a swift playground. I got the conversion to work, but I need to make the code "speak" with AVFoundation. How can I decode the morse code string to play the short beep for every '.' and the long beep for every '-'?

Here's my code so far:

```
func speakTheCode(message: String) {
    var speaker = AVAudioPlayer()

    let longBeep = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep_long", ofType: "mp3")!)
    let shortBeep = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep_short", ofType: "mp3")!)

    try! speaker = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: longBeep)
    try! speaker = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: shortBeep)

    speaker.prepareToPlay()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to decode the string to the correspondingly audio.

```
func speakTheCode(message: String) {
    var audioItems: [AVPlayerItem] = []

    guard let longPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep_long", ofType: "mp3"),
    let shortPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep_short", ofType: "mp3") else {
        print("Path is not availabel")
        return
    }

    let longBeep = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: longPath))
    let shortBeep = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: shortPath))

    for character in message.characters {
        if character == Character("-") {
            audioItems.append(longBeep)
        } else if character == Character(".") {
            audioItems.append(shortBeep)
        }
    }

    let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: audioItems)
    player.play()

}

speakTheCode(message: "..--..")
```

Comment: Why is `speaker` declared outside of the loop? Why create a throwaway instance of `AVAudioPlayer()`?

Comment: And the call to `play()` does not block. The loop will run really fast kicking off several concurrent instances of audio players.

Comment: my faults, I just take the origin code for example, I updated my answer. It should be a sequence of playeritems.

Comment: Now there is a problem with the code... the playground crashes when I press convert. No build time errors, just runtime.

Comment: Is it something to do with the URL of the audio? I'm making this in the swift playgrounds app on my iPad and I'm not sure how that compares to inside Xcode

Comment: you can use `guard` to make sure whether the `path` is available or not.